blip2 type mismatch exception
I'm trying to create an image captioning model using hugging face blip2 model on colab. My code was working fine till last week (Nov 8) but it gives me an exception now.
To install packages I use the following command:
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/huggingface/peft.git transformers bitsandbytes datasets

To load blip2 processor and model I use the following code:
model_name = "Salesforce/blip2-opt-2.7b"
processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = Blip2ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name,device_map="auto",load_in_8bit=False)

I use the following code to generate captions:
def generate_caption(processor, model, image_path):
  image = PILImage.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
  print("image shape:" + image.size)

  device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

  # Preprocess the image
  inputs = processor(images=image, return_tensors="pt").to(device)

  print("Input shape:", inputs['pixel_values'].shape)

  print("Device:", device) # Additional debugging

  for key, value in inputs.items():
    print(f"Key: {key}, Shape: {value.shape}")

  # Generate caption
  with torch.no_grad():
      generated_ids = model.generate(**inputs)
      caption = processor.decode(generated_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

  return caption

here is the code that uses this method to generate captions:
  image_path = "my_image_path.jpg"
  caption = generate_caption(processor, model, image_path)
  print(f"{image_path}: {caption}"

finally, this is the outputs and errors of running the code above:
image shape:  (320, 240)
Input shape: torch.Size([1, 3, 224, 224])
Device: cuda
Key: pixel_values, Shape: torch.Size([1, 3, 224, 224])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------   
.
.
.
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/blip_2/modeling_blip_2.py in generate(self, pixel_values, input_ids, attention_mask, interpolate_pos_encoding, **generate_kwargs)
   2314         if getattr(self.config, "image_token_index", None) is not None:
   2315             special_image_mask = (input_ids == self.config.image_token_index).unsqueeze(-1).expand_as(inputs_embeds)
-> 2316             inputs_embeds[special_image_mask] = language_model_inputs.flatten()
   2317         else:
   2318             logger.warning_once(

RuntimeError: shape mismatch: value tensor of shape [81920] cannot be broadcast to indexing result of shape [0]

I have searched the internet and used various AI models for help but to no avail. My guess is that this is a package update problem since my code had no problem last week. (I tried to restore my code to Nov 8 version but it throws an exception.) Moreover, I don't understand how 81920 is calculated in the error message.

FWIW I was able to reproduce the bug but not resolve it. Did you report it as an issue on the transformers repo?

I had the same issue. You need to add a prompt in the processor:
prompt = " "

inputs = processor(images=image, text=prompt, return_tensors="pt").to(device="cuda", dtype=torch.float16)

Hope it helps.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I'm pretty sure it's a model issue. I've been having issues with https://huggingface.co/Salesforce/blip2-flan-t5-xl since their update on Thursday, both on an older and the newest transformers version. The screenshot of a past model version (gets saved automatically, on .cache/huggingface/hub on a Mac) worked.
